# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

These two sections my code are giving the following error message.

```
def Simpsons(a, b, n, f, x):
    h=(b-a)/n
    s = 0.
    step = a + h 
    for i in range(1, int(n/2)):
        s += 4*f(x)
        #step += 2*h

    step = a + 2 * h
    for i in range(2, int(n/2 - 1)):
        s += 2*f(x)
        #step += 2 * h

    area = (h/3) * (f(a) + f(b) + s)
    return area
```

and

```
for i in range(0, len(list_n)):
    for j in range(0, len(Functions)):
        x = np.linspace(a, b, list_n[i])
        error_simp[j, i] = Exact_intergrals[j] - Simpsons(0, 1,         list_n[i], Functions[j], x)
print(error_simp)
```

Give this message:

```
   error_simp[j, i] = Exact_intergrals[j] - Simpsons(0, 1, list_n[i], Functions[j], x)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Why is this? everything I have tried does not get rid of it.

Comment: Make sure if you post Python code that you reproduce your indentation accurately. Otherwise you're introducing new problems in the code people are trying to find problems in.

Comment: side remark: you should make a case destinction in Simpson (integration) if n is even or odd. The simpson rule can be extended to an odd number of intervalls, by handling the last intervall seperately (Fitting a parabola into the last 3 points and integrate between the last 2 points only)

Comment: What is `error_simp`?  Shape, dtype?  What does the RHS produce?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to load array into error_simp[j,i] which might be able to contain only float numbers.

Here is a simple example which illustrates this error:

```
import numpy
b = numpy.zeros(5)
b[0] = numpy.zeros(5) - 1
```

Produces the same error.

Looks like either `Simpsons` function returns an array or `Exact_intergrals[j]` contains an array.

If you need to save arrays in `error_simp` matrix, try to add one more dimension:

```
error_simp = np.zeros((rows, cols, additional_dimension_size))
```

(Another option is to explicitly set `dtype=object` option in constructor, but it's much slower and not recommended).

There are a few similar questions that might help: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803256/error-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-python-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Your Simpsons function when given an array returns an array of the same size:

```
In [335]: Simpsons(0,1,10, lambda x:x**2, np.linspace(0,1,3))
Out[335]: array([ 0.03333333,  0.2       ,  0.7       ])
```

You don't show how `error_simp` is initialized.  The use `error_simp[j, i]=...` and the error suggests that

```
np.zeros((n,m), float)
```

or something like that.

For further help you need to specify what you expect to put in `error_simp`.   If `x` is the same for all elements, you could create a matching 3d array.  If `x` has different lengths, it will have to be `dtype=object`.  But I like to discourage this usage by beginners.  Such an array is little more than a glorified (or debased) list of lists.  It's easy to have unrealistic expectations of what you can do with such an array.

=========

Looking more carefully at

```
for i in range(0, len(list_n)):
    for j in range(0, len(Functions)):
        x = np.linspace(a, b, list_n[i])
```

you probably are creating different size `x`.  You don't show `list_n`, but it probably is something like `[10,12,14,...]`, testing this function for different `n`.